# How to enter numbers in a Leaflet markers (circles)

Tags: r, leaflet

I have the following dataframe.

```
head(branches)
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  population_percentage      Lat     Long        Freq
                  <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl>
1                 0.6 % 41.99575 21.43122 0.005875253
2                 0.6 % 41.99575 21.43122 0.006253363
3                 0.8 % 41.99575 21.43122 0.008405683
4                   1 % 41.98857 21.45733 0.009816326
5                 1.1 % 41.99977 21.42708 0.010528918
6                 1.2 % 42.00731 21.36529 0.011750505
```

Using leaflet, I plot the map.

```
leaflet(branches) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addCircles(lng = ~Long, lat = ~Lat, weight = 10, color = "#03F", opacity = 0.5,
             radius = ~sqrt(Freq) * 30, popup = ~ population_percentage    
  )
```

What I want to do now, is to have inside the bubles (or circles) the opulation_percentage as shown in the example below.

[image]

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are looking for, but if you want to group the items and show them with numbers inside the circles you can use `clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()` inside `addCircles` or `addCircleMarkers`

Comment: Yes, im looking exactly that (https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/blob/master/example/map.png). But im not sure how to specify the code.

Comment: `leaflet(branches) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addCircles(lng = ~Long, lat = ~Lat, weight = 10, color = "#03F", opacity = 0.5,
             radius = ~sqrt(Freq) * 30, popup = ~ population_percentage, clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()   
  )` Does this not work?

Comment: No, I tried that. Im getting the following error: Error in addCircles(., lng = ~Long, lat = ~Lat, weight = 10, color = "#03F",  : 
  unused argument (clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())

Comment: Change `addCircles` to `addCircleMarkers`

Comment: Yes, it worked. But this grouping is counting the number of elements, not the percentage of each element. Is there a way to change that?

Comment: For instance, I don't want to count the number of branches that are close to each other, but rather the percentage of a population thats within that group.

Comment: You might need to look into this https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#customising-the-clustered-markers